# Is there a way to store two months of history in my Ripple testnet?

Tags: blockchain, ripple, xrp

I have a ripple testnet and mainnet. Their history storage configurations are equal. However, in my mainnet my complete_ledgers result returns a first block whose closing time was in the beginning of October and in the testnet the first ledger that is available is from mid-November. The only other significative difference between the two configuration files is the node size (small for testnet and medium for mainnet, as advised). Below follows the configuration for the history block.

Is there any difference in the configuration of the mainnet and testnet that i am not accounting for? Do you have any suggestions on solving this?

```
[node_db]
type=NuDB
path=/data/nudb
advisory_delete=0

# How many ledgers do we want to keep (history)?
# Integer value that defines the number of ledgers
# between online deletion events
online_delete=700000

[ledger_history]
# How many ledgers do we want to keep (history)?
# Integer value (ledger count)
# or (if you have lots of TB SSD storage): 'full'
350000
```

I have seen in the documentation that the ledger_history should never be greater that the online_deletion and vice-versa, so I tried setting the ledger_history to the same value as I have in online_deletion, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the testnet and mainnet's chains do not progress in the same way or the configurations affect the chains differently, so I increased the ledger history and online_deletion's values for the testnet and I am now storing as much history as needed

Comment: Welcome to the Stack overflow 's community! Thanks to share the solution with the community. Please, close the questions as soon as you could. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The ledgers your rippled node can sync depends highly on the peers it is connected to.

Your node can only download as much history as its connected peers can provide. So if you want to download 700k ledgers but your peers only hold 100k ledgers, then your max downloadable history will be 100k ledgers.

Probably due to the config change and therefore restart of rippled, you got connected to different peers which hold more history and your node was able to download as much as it requested.

You can check your peers with the command:

`rippled peers`

and see what history they can provide in the `complete_ledgers` property.

Best,
Daniel